# how to display the filenames in ascending order according to their sizes of current directory using system call in c?

Tags: c, sorting, system-calls

I am trying to sort file names according to their sizes using a system call in c.

I tried this...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    DIR *dir1, *dir2;
    int fd, cur_size, min_size;
    struct dirent *dirent1, *dirent2;
    struct stat st1, st2;
    char min_file_name[1000];
    char filename[1000];
    dir1 = opendir(".");
    while ((dirent1 = readdir(dir1)) != NULL) {
        min_size = INT_MAX;
        dir2 = opendir(".");
        while ((dirent2 = readdir(dir2)) != NULL) {
            stat(dirent2->d_name, &st1);
            cur_size = st1.st_size;
            strcpy(filename, dirent2->d_name);
            if (cur_size <= min_size && strcmp(min_file_name, filename) != 0) {
                min_size = cur_size;
                strcpy(min_file_name, dirent2->d_name);
            }
        }
        printf("File name = %s || size = %d \n", min_file_name, min_size);
    }
}
```

Output

```
amol@amol-Ideapad-320:~/AOS$ gcc q3.c
amol@amol-Ideapad-320:~/AOS$ ./a.out

File name =  || size = 0 
File name =  || size = 0 
File name =  || size = 0 
File name =  || size = 0
```

Comment: Can you give a basic example of inputs and expected outputs? Because this doesn't look like any reasonable sorting solution (the outer loop doesn't do anything useful, so you're really just recomputing the smallest file a number of times equal to the number of entries in the directory?). To do the sorting properly, you'd either need to stores file names and sizes in an array of `struct`s holding both pieces of information and sort that, or (much less efficient on I/O, but minimal memory requirements) do some nonsense that involves finding the smallest remaining size in the input, printing...

Comment: ... the items of that size, then looping to find the next smallest size and printing all items of that size, etc. Even optimized, it would involve rereading the input directory a number of times equal to the number of unique sizes in the directory, which means the same directories that would eat more memory to sort in memory would cost *way* more to sort without using memory.

Comment: Amol_G, Read the directory into a linked list of filenames and sizes, sort the list, then print.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Any particular reason to recommend linked list, over some homegrow `vector`-like setup? At least with the contiguous memory they can use `qsort` instead of *also* reimplementing sorting from scratch.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Listed list suggested for its simplicity.  After forming a listed list, easy enough to copy info to a right-sized allocated array and then call `qsort()`. Reimplementing sorting from scratch not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't understand the logic in your nested loop approach.

To produce a list in a given order, you can construct a sorted list of the entries in the directory and print that.

Here is a modified version using a simplistic quadratic insertion sort on a linked list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

struct entry {
    char *name;
    long long int size;
    struct entry *next;
};

int main() {
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *dp;
    struct stat st;
    struct entry *head = NULL, *ep, **npp;

    dir = opendir(".");
    if (dir == NULL) {
        perror("cannot open directory");
        return 1;
    }
    while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        ep = calloc(sizeof(*ep), 1);
        if (ep == NULL) {
            perror("cannot allocate memory");
            return 1;
        }
        ep->name = strdup(dp->d_name);
        if (ep->name == NULL) {
            perror("cannot allocate memory");
            return 1;
        }
        if (!stat(dp->d_name, &st)) {
            ep->size = st.st_size;
        }
        for (npp = &head; *npp && (*npp)->size <= ep->size; npp = &(*npp)->next)
            continue;
        ep->next = *npp;
        *npp = ep;
    }
    closedir(dir);
    for (ep = head; ep; ep = ep->next) {
        printf("%s\n", ep->name);
    }
    while ((ep = head) != NULL) {
        head = ep->next;
        free(ep->name);
        free(ep);
    }
    return 0;
}
```